# Binding Update of a Read-Only Property in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have a ListBox that is bound, via dependency property, to a `ObservableCollection<object>`. I am using a `DataTemplateSelector` to determine which type of objects, based off of class type, are found in the ObservableCollection then I apply the appropriate DataTemplate. Multiple objects of any class type is possible.

Part of my model class is below. It has been edited to show points of interest only:

```
public class IPUpdater
{
   public IPUpdater()
   {
   }

   public string IPTransceiverInstall { get; set; }
   public string IPTransceiverFinal { get; set; }
   public Boolean IsFinal { get; set; }       

   public string IPTransceiver
   {
       get
       {
           return IPTransceiverAddress();
       }
   }

   private string IPTransceiverAddress()
   {
       if (!IsFinal)
           return IPTransceiverInstall;
       else
           return IPTransceiverFinal;
   }

}
```

`IPTransceiver` is bound to a TextBox within the XAML DataTemplate when the appropriate IPUpdater template is used. `IsFinal` is bound to a CheckBox within the same template.

**Question:** How do I force the TextBox to register that `IPTransceiver` has changed? I thought about trying to set a DependencyProperty equal to IPTransceiver, but I wasn't sure how to initially set it's value if there's more than one instance of the class in the Listbox.

`TwoWay` and `OneWayToSource` binding modes are not available for a read-only property. I can verify that `IsFinal` updates when the CheckBox value has changed. I've even tried to force `IPTransceiverAddress()` to trigger when `IsFinal` updates. None of the above have caused the TextBox to update. The only way I have been able to get the box to update is by repeating the SQLite Query, which I'd like to avoid.

Thanks!

Comment: First of all you're not implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`, therefore the UI has no way to know when changes occur. Second, how can a READ-ONLY property Change??

Comment: I'm using dependency properties instead of `INotifyPropertyChanged`. The property is read-only from outside the class. Does that make sense? I don't want the property to be set external to the class.

Comment: `I'm using dependency properties instead of INotifyPropertyChanged.` [That's wrong](http://kentb.blogspot.com.ar/2009/03/view-models-pocos-versus.html). Also, I don't see that your code is doing DependencyProperties at all. Please clarify. Also, if your property is readonly outside the class, create a `private setter` instead.

Comment: Oops! sorry for the duplicated comment. SO gave me an error on submit so I retried several times =(

Comment: Why is that wrong? I thought using DependencyProperties vs. INotifyPropertyChanged was a matter of preference? But, at this point I'm planning to stick with DPs, because of the time invested. To clarify though, I have DPs in the VM, not in the model. Would it be appropriate to put them into the model?

Comment: Did you read the post by Kent Boogart I linked to? It clearly states the reasons for which using `DependencyProperties` in the ViewModel is a bad idea. I would also add that I'd rather not tie my ViewModels (which should be view-agnostic and thus not depend on any UI technology) to WPF by having them reference the `System.Windows.DependencyProperty` class. So, I'm sorry if you already did a lot of this, but my point still stands it's a bad idea.

Comment: Also, I think you might have a misconception here. Those properties you posted are NOT DependencyProperties. They are regular POCO properties, and your problem is that I don't see any `INotifyPropertyChanged`s in your code.

Comment: You are correct, I did not implement any DPs in the model above. I only have DPs in the VM that bind to my various controls. My question was how to go about getting the textbox to update when the property `IsFinal` changes?

Comment: Again: `NotifyPropertyChange("IsFinal")` is all you need.

Comment: Post something for the answer so I can mark it as such. I'll explain what I had to do with `INotifyPropertyChanged` and possibly you could explain why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any classes you expect to use as binding sources should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Your ViewModels (as well as your models, if you plan to bind the Views directly to them) should implement this interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event in order for the WPF binding engine to reflect these changes in the UI.

Comment: The only way I could get this to work was by adding `OnPropertyChanged("IPEthernet")` and `OnPropertyChanged("IPEthernet")` to the `IsFinal` setter.

Comment: And yes... I'm relatively new and behind the curve in all this!